# Pandas sort index as an integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which was built out of a CSV. When I am converting this to html using `df.to_html()` it is giving me a sort order different from the CSV file.

When I print the dataframe on the console it gives me the following output

```
   reasons_for_make_good
0                   None
1                   None
10                  None
11                  None
12                  None
13                  None
14                  None
15                  None
16                  None
17                  None
18                  None
19                  None
2                   None
3                   None
4                   None
5                   None
6                   None
7                   None
8                   None
9                   None
```

Why is the index sorted as a string, is it possible to sort it as an integer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try convert index to `int` by [`Index.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.astype.html) and then [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
df = df.sort_index()
```